# PHP Date_format Warning

Tags: php

I have a form with dropdown tags:

```
MONTH   DAY  YEAR  HOURS  MINS
```

And when I retrieve the values while submiting the form:

```
$selMonth = htmlentities($_POST['regmonth']);
$selDay = htmlentities($_POST['regday']);
$selYear = htmlentities($_POST['regyear']);
$selHours = htmlentities($_POST['reghours']);
$selMins = htmlentities($_POST['regmins']);

$date = date_create("".$selDay."-".$selMonth."-".$selYear." ".$selHours.":".$selMins."");
$actual_date = date_format($date, 'd-M-Y H:i');
$timestamp = strtotime($actual_date);
//echo $actual_dt.','.$timestamp;
```

Iam getting the correct date but have a warning always:

```
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\source\form.php on line 37.
```

Could anyone suggest why I was getting this warning.

Comment: Are you getting your actual results?

Comment: check what `$date` returns before using `date_format`

Comment: use `$date = strtotime(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM )`, don't make it complicated

Comment: @Saqueib: or mktime() and date()

Comment: @Ranjith: Iam getting the output correctly, but this warning displays always

Comment: @Saranya : I don't think any error on that [chechout here](https://ideone.com/ng07qF)

Comment: That's because `DateTime` uses a `resource` as first parameter, not a `string`.
[php.net/datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)
`string date_format ( DateTimeInterface $object , string $format )`

Comment: @OCIA : If like this [how this will work?](https://ideone.com/ng07qF) Even me also define as string.

Comment: More like this: [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ztNhlu). Or as @Saqueib suggested... Or: `$dateformatted = date("d-m-Y H:i", strtotime("Y-m-d H:i"));`

Comment: No. I'm asking is there any issue in `date_format(string, 'd-m-Y H:i')` instead of `date_format(object, 'd-m-Y H:i')`?

Comment: Best way is use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) object to convert your date.

Comment: @Ranjith Yes, because date_format expects an object as a parameter, not a string. So you first have to convert a date-string into an object before you feed it into the `date_format` function.

Comment: @OCIA : Fine. Thanks for you tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$selMonth = htmlentities($_POST['regmonth']);
$selDay = htmlentities($_POST['regday']);
$selYear = htmlentities($_POST['regyear']);
$selHours = htmlentities($_POST['reghours']);
$selMins = htmlentities($_POST['regmins']);

$date = ("".$selYear."-".$selMonth."-".$selDay." ".$selHours.":".$selMins."");
$timestamp = Date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($date));
```